# C#7 tuple & async

Tags: c#, tuples, c#-7.0

Old format:

```
private async Task<Tuple<SomeArray[], AnotherArray[], decimal>>         
GetInvoiceDetailAsync(InvoiceHead invoiceHead) { ... }
```

How can you do that in C#7 with new tuples format?

Comment: `Task<(SomeArray[], AnotherArray[], decimal)>`

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Step 1: add the ValueTuple nuget package to your project.

Step 2: as Lucas says in his comment, change the syntax to:

```
private async Task<(SomeArray[], AnotherArray[], decimal)>GetInvoiceDetailAsync(
    InvoiceHead invoiceHead) 
{ 
    ...
    return (x, y, z); 
}
```

Note though that you can also then add names to those tuple items, along the lines of:

```
private async Task<(SomeArray[] x, AnotherArray[] y, decimal z)>GetInvoiceDetailAsync(
    InvoiceHead invoiceHead) 
{ 
    ... 
    return (x, y, z); 
}
```

And you can then access them as those names, rather than `Item1`, `Item2` and `Item3`.

Comment: Shouldn't you also change the Generic argument that it no longer includes the `Tuple<>` statement?

Comment: @Icepickle, now I'm confused as I thought I did that. Copy paste error, I think <blush/>. Now fixed.

Comment: > "Note though that you can also then add names to those tuple items"

I tried this, but got only `Item1`/`Item2` instead of named fields after `.Wait()` for `Task` from `public async static Task<(string status, T result)> GetObjectAsync<T>(string folder, string fileName)`

Comment: You don't need the ValueTuple nuget package if you have .NET Framework 4.7, .NET Core 2.0, and .NET Standard 2.0 or above.